# Simulating time and Akka schedulers

Tags: scala, akka, scheduler

I am building a multi-agent simulation using Akka and as such would like to run simulations faster than real time.  Specifically, I would like to configure the Akka scheduler so that instead of advancing by some underlying fixed time step, the scheduler advances from one scheduled event to the next (which obviously might involve substantially different time steps between events).

Put slightly differently, I would like the scheduler to behave as if it was a kind of priority queue where priority is given by an event's simulation timestamp.

Is this clear? If so, is what I want to do possible using the default scheduler for an Actor System? If this is not possible, then how would I go about rolling my own scheduler using existing Akka components to accomplish this task.

Comment: Does it have to be a scheduler?  Why not just a recursive function that dispatches messages to your Agents?

Comment: @RamonJ.RomeroyVigil Sorry I don't follow. Can you provide a bit more description of what you have in mind?

Comment: I'll write an answer with an example.  If it's not what you're looking for I can always delete...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with akka schedulers.  From the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/scala/scheduler.html) (emphasis mine):

> Sometimes the need for making things happen in the future arises, and
>   where do you go look then? Look no further than ActorSystem! There you
>   find the scheduler method that returns an instance of
>   akka.actor.Scheduler, this instance is unique per ActorSystem and is
>   used internally **for scheduling things to happen at specific points
>   in time**.

However, you could always accomplish the same thing with a recursive function.  Let's say your "real time" functionality looks something like:

```
def periodicFunction() : Unit = ???  //whatever you're doing to Agents

//periodicFunction is called every 10 seconds
actorSystem.scheduler().schedule(0 seconds, 10 seconds)(periodicFunction())
```

Your simulation code could simply be:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def fasterThanRealTimeLoop(n : Int) = 
  if(n > 0) {
    periodicFunction()

    fasterThanRealTimeLoop(n-1)
  }
```

Then you could simulate 20 runs with

```
fasterThanRealTimeLoop(20)
```

This functionality could further be wrapped to encapsulate both possiblities:

```
val realtimeMode : Boolean = ??? //some configuration setting

val periodicArgs : Either[FiniteDuration, Int] = 
  if(realtimeMode) Left(10 Seconds) else Right(20)

periodicArgs.left.foreach { period => 
  actorSystem.scheduler().schedule(0 seconds, period)(periodicFunction())
}

periodicArgs.right.foreach { count => 
  fasterThanRealTimeLoop(count)
}
```

This code will now call the correct type of loop (timed or fast-as-possible) depending on the configuration setting.

Comment: @RamonJ.RomeroyVigil Thanks.  I don't think this recursive function call would work for what I want to do.  What I want, I think, is for the Akka scheduler to behave like a priority queue where objects in the queue are ordering in terms of simulation time.

Comment: @davidrpugh You are welcome.  As I said at the top of my answer I don't think scheduler has that in its bag of tricks.  Happy hacking.